# Close pop-up menu by clicking anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, popup

I have the following code:

```
var toggleButton = $('.menu-toggle'),
timerDelay;
toggleButton.on("click", function() {
    var elem = $(this),
    menu = elem.siblings('ul'),
    parent = elem.parent(),
    parentParent = parent.parent(),
    pageH = $(window).height();
    elem.toggleClass('pressed');
    menu.stop(true);
    clearTimeout(timerDelay);
    if (menu.is('.scrollable')) {
        menu.css({"max-height": pageH - 80});
    }
    parent.toggleClass('showed');
    if (menu.is('.parent')) {
        parentParent.toggleClass('showed');
    }
    if (menu.is('.hidden')) {
        menu.css({"height": "100%", "padding": 5}).toggleClass('hidden showed');
    } else {
        menu.toggleClass('hidden showed');
        if (menu.is('.nodelay')) {
            menu.css({"height": 0, "padding": ""});
        } else {
            timerDelay = setTimeout(function() {
                menu.css({"height": 0, "padding": ""});
            }, 450);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code for a pop-up menu. The problem is that it requires clicking on a specific button to close it. I'm trying to also make it close whenever the user clicks anywhere on the page.

Is there a way?

---

Maybe I gave the wrong code. This is another section:

```
$(document).click(function (e)
{
var container = $("#wrapper");

if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 &&      event.target.id!=="menu-toggle")
{
    container.addClass("toggled"); 
}
});
```

Could I mix it with this?

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    container.hide();
}
});
```

Comment: Can you give a working example in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Comment: Would a live example work? http://djdb.me/ (it's the menu on the top, near the logo)

Answer (score 0):

Without a working example...

You can do something like this:

```
var toggleButton = $('.menu-toggle'),
    timerDelay;

toggleButton.on("click", toggleDisplay);

function toggleDisplay() {

    var elem = $(this),
        menu = elem.siblings('ul'),
        parent = elem.parent(),
        parentParent = parent.parent(),
        pageH = $(window).height();
    elem.toggleClass('pressed');
    menu.stop(true);
    clearTimeout(timerDelay);
    if (menu.is('.scrollable')) {
        menu.css({"max-height": pageH - 80});
    }
    parent.toggleClass('showed');
    if (menu.is('.parent')) {
        parentParent.toggleClass('showed');
    }
    if (menu.is('.hidden')) {
        menu.css({"height": "100%", "padding": 5}).toggleClass('hidden showed');
        $(window).addEventListener('click', toggleButton);
    } else {
        menu.toggleClass('hidden showed');
        if (menu.is('.nodelay')) {
            menu.css({"height": 0, "padding": ""});
        } else {
            timerDelay = setTimeout(function() {
                menu.css({"height": 0, "padding": ""});
            }, 450);
        }
        $(window).removeEventListener('click', toggleDisplay);
    }
}
```

`addEventListener` to the `window` when it is show. When window is clicked run the toggle function.

`removeEventListener` from the `window` when it is hidden.

**One issue** this still has is that if the menu is clicked it will still hide, so you would need to add logic that if the menu is clicked to `return;`

**Update** After looking at you're live example.... Instead of using `window` you can use `'.blog-content'`

Comment: `toggleButton.on("click", );` missing `handler` `toggleDDisplay` ?

Comment: Yes.... sorry should be `toggleButton.on("click", toggleDisplay);` and the function should just be `toggleDisplay`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).one("click",function() {
  if ($(".showed").is(":visible")) {
    $(".pressed").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help, provided your menu has a class 'menu'.

```
$('.menu, .menu-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if($('.menu').hasClass('showed')){
        //code to hide menu 
        // i have clicked the toggle button here since the logic to hide menu is not separate in your code
        toggleButton.click();
    }
});
```

Here is an example jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/okbpxb14/